# php mutiple file upload with two inputs

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a file upload with a image and a file.
I have been trying to fix it for ages and have not managed to get it to work.
(I am a newbie)
php:

```
$target_dir1 = "/Files/images";
$target_dir2 = "/Files/files";
$target_file1 = $target_dir1 . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
$target_file2 = $target_dir2 . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][1]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$fileType1 = pathinfo($target_file1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileType2 = pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if files already exists
if (file_exists($target_file1)) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, file already exists.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if (file_exists($target_file2)) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, file already exists.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check files size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"][0] > 1500000) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, your file is too large.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOk= 0;
}
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"][1] > 1500000) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, your file is too large.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0], $target_file1)) {
        $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"][0]). " has been uploaded.</div>\");</script>";
    }
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "error1";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][1], $target_file2)) {
        $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"][1]). " has been uploaded.</div>\");</script>";
    }

}
```

html:

```
    <form class="col-lg-3" role="form" method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?page=Upload");?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file">
  </div>
  </form>
```

for some reason it does not work.
What I want it to do is upload both files to the directories.
**Update**

I later figured that all I had to was remove the slash in front of both $target_dir and then it worked.

Comment: What _does not work_ Please be more specific

Comment: Also: how your form is submitted?

Comment: It gives me too large error or just does not upload.

Comment: @fusion3k it is submitted by a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you confusing yourself. For `image`, keep `name` as `image[]`. And, do the needful changes below.

```
<form class="col-lg-3" role="form" method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?page=Upload");?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file">
  </div>
</form>

<?php

$target_dir1 = "/Files/images";
$target_dir2 = "/Files/files";
$target_file1 = $target_dir1 . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$target_file2 = $target_dir2 . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOkImage = 1;
$uploadOkFile = 1;
$fileType1 = pathinfo($target_file1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileType2 = pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if files already exists
if (file_exists($target_file1)) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, file already exists.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOkImage = 0;
}
if (file_exists($target_file2)) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, file already exists.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOkFile = 0;
}

// Check files size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 1500000) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, your file is too large.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOkImage= 0;
}
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1500000) {
    $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> Sorry, your file is too large.</div>\");</script>";
    $uploadOkFile = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOkImage == 0) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file1)) {
        $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</div>\");</script>";
    }
}

if ($uploadOkFile == 0) {
    echo "error1";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {
        $msg .= "<script>document.write( \"<div class='alert alert-info alert-css'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</div>\");</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get too large error even though the file size of both is less then 2mb.